# understanding recursion stack sum_integers

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, stack

I am doing a practice problem on recursion.

**Implement sum_integers(n) to calculate the sum of all integers from  1  to    using recursion. For example, sum_integers(3) should return  6  ( 1+2+3 ).**

I solved the problem without really understanding what I actually did...

```
def sum_integers(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n + sum_integers(n-1)
    pass
```

The base case, I understand.

lets say we call `sum_integers(3)`

```
sum_integers(3)
  sum_integers(2)
      sum_integers(1)
         sum_integers(0)
            return 0
```

I don't understand once I `return 0` what/how is it going back up the stack.

In my head this is what's happening

- 0 + sum_integers(1) = 0 + 1
- 0 + 1 + sum_integers(2) = 0  + 1 + 2
- 0 + 1 + 2 + sum_integers(3) = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3

I don't know  for sure though. I'm just trying to understand it a bit better.

Comment: Your final thought is right, so what do you not understand ?

Comment: @azro I guess I wanted to make sure my thought process was correct. It's still a bit fuzzy

Comment: To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0 + 1 + 2 + sum_integers(3) = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3` is not really correct, an easier way to see it could be

```
sum_integers(3)             # go down in recursion
3 + sum_integers(2)         # go down in recursion
3 + 2 + sum_integers(1)     # go down in recursion
3 + 2 + 1 + sum_integers(0) # go down in recursion
3 + 2 + 1 + 0               # stop because 'return 0'
3 + 2 + 1                   # go back and apply the plus
3 + 3                       # go back and apply the plus
6                           # go back and apply the plus
```